# Smooth handle attachment vs Weinstein handle attachment

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, contact-geometry, contact-topology

Given a closed smooth manifold $M$ of dimension $n$, to which we attach a $k$-handle $H_k$.
Take $T^{\ast} M$, can one realize $T^{\ast} (M\cup H_k)$ as a result of symplectic or Weinstein handle attached to $T^{\ast} M$, when we see $T^{\ast} M$ as a Weinstein manifold. Can it be done for all k? If not, can it be done at least for all $k\leq n/2$?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How can you attach handles to a manifold without boundary?

Comment: To YHBKJ: Do you mean in a smooth category? If yes, there is a handle decomposition, and you can glue extra handles, say by doing surgery. Say you have a sphere, you add a 1-handle and you get torus.

Comment: Then the answer is obviously no, because there is no exact Lagrangian embedding from $S^2$ to $T^\ast T^2$.

Comment: Sergey: In the operation you describe, I think you consider the 3-ball and attach a (three dimensional) 1-handle to its boundary. Then it is true that the boundary of this three dimensional handlebody is the torus.

If a smooth manifold $M$ is equipped with a Morse function $f$ which induces its handlebody decomposition, then it is true that $(T^\ast M, \lambda, f)$ has an induced Weinstein handlebody decomposition: For each critical point of $f$ you attach a Weinstein handle of that index.